# How can I untrack files in Git according to my .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have tracked many many files early, but I don't want Git to track them any more from now on.

Can I untrack those files according to a `.gitignore` file?

There are too many files and they are separated in many different directories, so it is not practical to remove them one-by-one, instead, I hope they can be untracked according to patterns in a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to remove the files from the index.

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

and then add

```
git add .
```

Finally commit:

```
git commit -a -m "Untrack ignored files!"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can stop tracking already-tracked files by staging a deletion of the file in the index:

```
git rm --cached path/to/ignored/file
```

... and committing.

With `--cached` this *won't* actually delete the file in your working copy. (I'm always paranoid and copy them somewhere safe first, anyway.)

Comment: I will upvote this for the paranoia and having a backup copy ready